# Pytest-allure filter by hosts

Tags: pytest, allure, pytest-xdist

Are there any ways to filter tests in Allure report by host after tests run with pytest-xdist?

I'm using allure-pytest==2.13.2 and allure-python-commons==2.13.2. I tried to add @allure.label decorators, but it doesn't helped me.